# Android app launch background color not changing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am making an android application using android studio. It works fine in light mode but when I turn on dark mode the launch screen(the initial screen shown on clicking the icon) has a black background.

in activity_main.xml I tried using

```
android:windowBackground="@color/white"
```

```
android:drawableTint="@color/white"
```

```
app:tint="@color/white"
```

but none of the above options worked for me.

Comment: That doesn't work anymore like that. Android has now a system splash screen. Which is shown before your first activity. So setting the background in the activity is too late. Check out the splash screen docs https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't related to these attributes that you mention :
the problem maybe that you don't  put color in dark mode in color.xml
with same wight color

- **in Night Mode:** `<color name="wight">#FFFFFF</color>`
- **in Dark Mode:** `<color name="wight">#FFFFFF</color>`